# How can I fix this Compiler error?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I'm getting a compiler error for this test:

```
@isTest public class TestDirectMailFilter {

public static testMethod void testMyController() {

Campaign c = new Campaign(); c.Name = 'Jacob for president'; c.Type = 'Direct Mail'; insert c;

ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(c);
**DirectMailfilter dmf = new DirectMailfilter(sc);**
System.assertEquals(1, dmf.getDmcampaigns().size()); }
}
```

The bold line is giving me this error:

> Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined:
>   [DirectMailfilter].(ApexPages.StandardController)

Here is the apex class I am trying to test:

```
public class DirectMailfilter {
public List<campaign> dmcampaigns {get;private set;} 
public DirectMailfilter(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller) {
         dmcampaigns = [SELECT StartDate, Type, Status, Name 
                     FROM Campaign 
                     WHERE Type = 'Direct Mail'];
     }

}
```

Seems like it should be simple, but I'm clearly missing something. What is it?

Comment: looks like your passing in a standard controller in the test, where in your class you have the constructor set up to take a standardSetController

Comment: @sfdc_ninja: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @MikeChale, just added it, was just glancing through and saw it while test code was running, didn't have time to explain an answer, but now I added it.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class the constructor is set up to take a StandardSetController

```
public DirectMailfilter(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller)
```

But in your test code, you are passing it a StandardController

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(c); 
DirectMailfilter dmf = new DirectMailfilter(sc);
```

While I don't know which is correct, the class or the test code, you need to either adjust the test code to take a `StandardSetController` or adjust the class constructor to take a `StandardController`.  Once they match, you should be all set.

Comment: That fixed the compiler error. It's giving another one, but I think you've solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For StandardSetController you should define the test like below or you can do it in the class or trigger.

```
PageReference myVfPage = Page.VisualForce API Name;
Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
List<You Custom Object > MyStuff = [ select id  from Your Custom Object Name];
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(MyStuff);
CustomControllerName ext = new CustomControllerName(setcon);
```